# Removing in-field quotes in csv file

Tags: python, parsing, csv, awk, quotes

Let's say we have a comma separated file (csv) like this:

```
"name of movie","starring","director","release year"
"dark knight rises","christian bale, anna hathaway","christopher nolan","2012"
"the dark knight","christian bale, heath ledger","christopher nolan","2008"
"The "day" when earth stood still","Michael Rennie,the 'strong' man","robert wise","1951"
"the 'gladiator'","russel "the awesome" crowe","ridley scott","2000"
```

As you can see from above, in lines 4 & 5 there is quotes within quotes. 
The output should look something like this:

```
"name of movie","starring","director","release year"
"dark knight rises","christian bale, anna hathaway","christopher nolan","2012"
"the dark knight","christian bale, heath ledger","christopher nolan","2008"
"The day when earth stood still","Michael Rennie,the strong man","robert wise","1951"
"the gladiator","russel the awesome crowe","ridley scott","2000"
```

How to get rid of such quotes (both single and double) that occur within quotes like this on a csv file. Note that comma within a single field is okay as the parser identifies that it's within quotes and takes it as one field. This is just a preprocessing step of arranging csv files so that it can be fed into multiple parsers to convert into any format we desire. 
Bash, awk, python all works. Please no perl, I'm sick of that language :D 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand how removing the first and last quote will help. The requirement is to have double quotes around each and every field in the csv file. If we don't have quotes between each field then field values that has comma within them can't be parsed.

Comment: My thought was that a CSV reader would not be able to parse that file since there are unescaped double-quotes. I imagined you would have to parse it yourself hence my suggestion. Though since they would have been removed anyway, removing the first and last quotes would have been unnecessary. I assumed you were already using the csv module... I guess not.

Comment: I don't understand why my question got a -1 :/

Comment: @crazyim5: while I can't be sure, some people regularly downvote questions where the OP doesn't show the work that's already been done (in cases where that's relevant.)  Here it would have been better to (say) post an `awk` solution that you'd tried and ask a specific question about why it wasn't doing what you wanted it to.

Comment: I'm fairly new to posting on stackoverflow, I'll keep that in mind and do it from next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
import csv

def remove_quotes(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in s if c not in ('"', "'"))

with open("fixquote.csv","rb") as infile, open("fixed.csv","wb") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow([remove_quotes(elem) for elem in line])
```

which produces

```
~/coding$ cat fixed.csv 
"name of movie","starring","director","release year"
"dark knight rises","christian bale, anna hathaway","christopher nolan","2012"
"the dark knight","christian bale, heath ledger","christopher nolan","2008"
"The day when earth stood still","Michael Rennie,the strong man","robert wise","1951"
"the gladiator","russel the awesome crowe","ridley scott","2000"
```

BTW, you might want to check the spelling of some of those names..

Comment: `if c not in ('"', "'")` could also be written as `if c not in """"'"""` :)

Comment: Ah, I would have expected the reader to choke on those unescaped double quotes.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: heavy!  Well, `'"'"'"` would work too, if it came to that, thanks to string literal concatenation. :^)

Comment: I did that. Thanks for guiding.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have one small issue though, how to avoid not getting empty quotes for fields that are null? If one of the field is missing then it should go "a","b",,"d" etc...

Answer (score 1):

With awk you can do something like:

```
awk -v Q='"' '{ gsub("[\"']","") ; gsub(",",Q "," Q) ; print Q $0 Q }'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think the python solution posted by DSM worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Split the values into an array. Iterate through the array removing any quotes, other than the first and last character. Hope it helps.