# Python regex to get some/not all quote marks out of csv file

Tags: python, regex, csv, double-quotes

i have a .csv file with all fields separated by double quotes, but some fields have random double quotes in them/ UPDATE this was a bit off and i'm including two lines, the second of which is a problem. in the original, i didn't have double quotes at the end, which is a problem with the first solution, which works otherwise but strips the quote before /n:

```
"20135025373","25","2013-08-24 00:00:00","WOOD","CHRISTY","","","2679 W. LONG CIRCLE","","LITTLETON","CO","80120","","3510862","2013-09-03 00:00:00","Monetary (Itemized)","Credit/Debit Card","Individual","","Issue Committee","A WHOLE LOT OF PEOPLE FOR JOHN MORSE","","","","N","N","0","STATEWIDE",""
```

"20135025373","10","2013-08-24 00:00:00","DAVIS","JOHN","","","2822  THIRD "","","BOULDER","CO","80304","","3510863","2013-09-03 00:00:00","Monetary (Itemized)","Credit/Debit Card","Individual","","Issue Committee","A WHOLE LOT OF PEOPLE FOR JOHN MORSE","","","","N","N","0","STATEWIDE",""

i tried this code, but it also strips the quotes at the beginning and end of the lines.

```
import re

with open('ColoSOS/2014_ContData.csv') as old, open('2014contx.csv', 'w') as new:
    new.writelines(re.sub(r'(?<!,)"(?!,)', '', line) for line in old)
```

any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: What was your expected output?

Comment: shoot us a few lines from the actual csv if you can.

Comment: Here are some lines from the file

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the `csv` module, begin by taking a look at [Removing in-field quotes in csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010557/removing-in-field-quotes-in-csv-file).

If you're looking to do this by using regular expression, I suppose this will suffice.

```
re.sub(r'(?<=[^,])"(?=[^,])', '', line)
```

See working [`Demo`](https://eval.in/144966)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match quotes at beginning and end of the line you could use this regex:

```
(?<!,|^)\"(?!,|$)
```

Instead of:

```
(?<!,)"(?!,)
```

see demo here: http://regex101.com/r/cI7mW5

Comment: thanks! this throws a "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" for some reason.

Comment: hmm.. according [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/cI7mW5#python) this should work with Python

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `csv` module instead of `re`? It probably already has this intelligence built-in.

I'm rusty on `csv`. The below code is not tested, but may give you a starting place.

```
import csv

with open('ColoSOS/2014_ContData.csv') as old, open('2014contx.csv', 'w') as new:
    reader = csv.reader(old, delimiter = ','; quotechar = '"')
    new.writelines(row) for row in reader
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html