# Cleaning a .csv (not create a new)

Tags: python, csv

I have an .csv when I try to convert to a DataFrame I have this error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 208: invalid start byte
```

I know is because the csv file contain simbols like ’ and “ ” and I want to clean it before convert to dataframe. I look how to achieve it but I only find something like this

[Removing in-field quotes in csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010557/removing-in-field-quotes-in-csv-file)

The solution they say is to create a new csv document, but I think is no so efficient...

It's possible to clean a .csv file from this strange characters without creating a new file?

Thanks

Comment: There are complications in replacing characters in a file.  In this case, if you tried to replace a two-byte Unicode character with an ASCII character then you need to make sure you use the two-byte Unicode equivalent, not the single byte ASCII.  Otherwise you will end-up just replacing one byte of the Unicode.  When overwriting text files you must keep the line-length (in bytes) the same.  Creating a new file is by far the simplest way to go.

Comment: And don't modify the .csv, only can create the DataFrame?